# How to ensure on destroy of a row, delete associated embedded data in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I currently have the following models/toy.rb file in my RoR project:

```
class ToysPurchased
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :user, :inverse_of => :toys_purchased
  referenced_in :toy
end
```

Is there a command similar to ActiveRecords dependent: :destroy to ensure that when I delete a `Toy` from the `Toy` table that was purchased (`ToysPurchased`), then that the embedded item in the `User` row is also deleted?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work for you (except for destroy)? I'm not sure you can mix `embedded_in` and `referenced_in` this way.

Comment: You should take a look at http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/referenced/1-1.html. Its explained at the end.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Its fine using `embedded_in` and `belongs_to` this way, just need to set `inverse_of: nil` so that the other side of association is not set, which might have some problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no way to do that easily because you can't associate your Toy to your ToyPurchases because ToyPurchases is an embedded document. You can do a after_destroy callback to do the job

```
class Toy
  after_destroy :delete_toys_purchased

  def delete_toys_purchased
    User.where('toys_purchased.id', self.toy_purchased_id).each do |u|
      u.toy_purchased.find(self.toy_purchased_id).delete
    end
  end
end
```